# filter_input behavior for integer input tag name

Tags: validation, filter-input

I have form inputs that have their name attribute in Integer like below

`<input type="hidden" name="100351312" value="test" />`

If I use 
    `echo filter_input( INPUT_POST, '100351312' )`
It returns NULL

Whereas
`echo $_POST['100351312']` prints the value correctly.

Answer (score 0):

filter_input really needs three inputs; the type, the variable (both of which you have) and the filter, which you don't have.  Here are some types of filters: http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php

That said, if you're using WordPress you can almost always find a WordPress helper function you can use instead of filter_input()

Comment: If I specify filter, It returns NULL again.

`filter_input( INPUT_POST, '100351312', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING )`